# Is there a notion of exploration-exploitation tradeoff in dynamic programming (or model-based RL)?

Tags: model-based-methods, exploration-exploitation-tradeoff, dynamic-programming

Is there a notion of exploration-exploitation tradeoff in dynamic programming (or model-based RL)?

Comment: Given that this is a one-line question, which may be fine, it may be a good idea to explain why you're asking this question or wondering this.

Comment: Not in dynamic programming no. If you have an unknown model then yes. The issue of RL is basically that you don't know the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an implicit notion of it in dynamic programming; say, if you have to make some sort of search over a subset of a state space and you are deciding whether to use BFS, *breath first search*, or DFS, *depth first search*, you are at least implicitly thinking on the best way to explore/exploit the state space.

As for model based RL, yes. There is explicit algorithms that mediate exploration and exploitation. One of them is UCB, *uper confidence bound*. One of the best examples of a model based reinforcement learning algorithm is AlphaGo. The algorithm uses a variation of UCB to explore the state space.